# Giving a prepared SOAP response by Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I have a client, I want to make the server off by changing endpoint for exceptional situations and I want to give a prepared response for the request. As there are many security issues for preparing the SOAP messages, I don't want to make a complex fully completed (fake/mock) webservice server.

Is there a way to make a web service server that will give a ready (prepared/saved) response? No need to bind with WSDL and/or XSD but only for some parameters, the server should give the same prepared response. It looks like a proxy server and also a mock server but I don't know how to call and research about how to do it.

So simply; how can I write a very basic web service server that would read the XML (get the request, the SOAP message but without binding or transforming to beans or Java objects) and give a prepared (saved XML) response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Even within the same Java program.
Use [Java HTTP Server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html).
few lines of code and you have functional http server.